# Images from S3 Bucket in iOS Messenger

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm making messenger bot. Images used in bot are stored in AWS S3 bucket. I know there is some problem (probably bug) with loading images on iOS. It's when image_url is without www, so if I loading image from url like https://www.example.com/images/x.jpg there is no problem, but when loading from https://example.com/images/x.jpg some images are not loaded. Is there any option to deal with it? I can't prepend www to s3 address, becouse it's not working. It returns error:

> The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.

Is there any option to use s3 bucket with www to make messenger on iOS loading all images?

Comment: How is the example.com domain configured, you need to change it to reflect what you want to achieve.

Comment: Example domain is s3 bucket url actually. I wanted to show that domains without www are making problems with iOS messenger app

Comment: Check your S3 bucket policy file.

Comment: I think your theory as to the root cause of iOS image issues is likely incorrect. Since iOS never speaks to S3 to view the images referenced by your bot it is unlikely an S3 <---> iOS issue. I serve many S3 hosted images via Messenger to iOS and the URLs never start with www.

Comment: @Ram, are you doing some special configuration to serve imiages from S3 on iOS Messenger?

Comment: Nothing at all - just plain old URLs.